# How to get all the descendants with every split as different row in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, graph, tree

I have a Pandas dataframe containing parent ids and child ids. I need help building an updated dataframe listing every descendant of each parent but if there are more than one descendent then it should split that into different row.

For example - In the graph below if there should be having 5 different rows having same parent i.e., [0,1,4,9], [0, 1, 4, 8], [0, 1, 3, 7], [0, 2, 5], [0, 2, 6]
[image]

Example-
[image]

Output should be 2 rows - [1, 2, 3, 4, 6] , [1, 2, 3, 5, 7]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, wouldn't it be better to treat this as a graph issue and use networkx?

Comment: I have tried recursion to get all the child but i am unable to split it into different rows

Answer (score 0):

Using a graph approach could entail loading the edge list as a `networkx` directed graph. Then find the sink nodes - nodes with no outgoing edges - and find the simple paths from node `1` to the sink nodes:

```
import pandas
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame(zip([1,2,3,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6,7]), columns=['parent_id', 'child_id'])
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='parent_id', target='child_id', edge_attr=None, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
sink_nodes = [node for node in G.nodes if G.out_degree(node) == 0]
paths = [list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, source=1, target=sink)) for sink in sink_nodes]
```

Output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]], [[1, 2, 3, 5, 7]]]
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same in Spark dataframe

Comment: This isn't done in `pandas`, it's done in `networkx`. I'm not sure if `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` will work with a Spark dataframe, otherwise you can [convert](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html) it to pandas first.